# Logical Expressions: Why does "str1 in str2 or str2 not in str1" return True for my print statement?

Tags: python, logical-operators, notin

Firstly, I apologise for the stupid question or any errors in my post! (This is my first post!)

Secondly, I have tried to look up the answer to this on Stack Overflow and also the RealPython website (Logical Expressions) but I still can't seem to wrap my head around why this piece of code returns a "True" to the last (uncommented) function call?

I am trying to answer the following question from the Ebook "Introduction to computation and programming using Python" -

"Write a function isIn that accepts two strings as arguments and returns True if either string occurs anywhere in the other, and False otherwise. Hint: you might want to use the built-in str operation in."

If anyone can explain (in layman terms) why the below piece of code is returning "True" to the last function call, I would be very grateful - Again apologies for the stupid question!

```
def isIn(string1, string2):
    """Input two strings 
       Returns 'True' if either strings are within each other
    """

    if string1 in string2 or string2 not in string1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# isIn('hello', 'hello')           # Prints True
# isIn('hello', 'hello world')     # Prints True   
isIn('hello world', 'world hello') # Prints True
```

Comment: It returns `True` because `string2` is not `in string1`. Did you mean `string1 in string2 or string2 in string1`, without the `not`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to include the "not in" expression in order to try to answer the question in the ebook but I do not think I am doing it correctly - apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your functions returns `True` ?

The if statement `if string1 in string2 or string2 not in string1` is made of 3 parts:

1. `string1 in string2`
2. `or`
3. `string2 not in string1`

And you have:

```
string1 = 'hello world'
string2 = 'world hello'
```

- Part 1 (`string1 in string2`) :

  It evaluates to False, because 'hello world' isn't in 'world hello'
- Part 3 (`string2 not in string1`):

  It evaluates to `True`, because 'world hello' is effectively not present in 'hello world'
- Part2, `or`:

  The `or` will give you:

  - `True` if at least one of the expression evaluates to `True`
  - `False` if all the expression evaluate to `False`

So you get `True`

But if you have used `and`, you would have get `False`

If sometimes you are in doubt, try some print like these:

```
# or:
print(True or True) # True
print(True or False) # True
print(False or False) # False

# and:
print(True and True) # True
print(True and False) # False
print(False and False) # false
```

Answering your comment:

No, 'hello world' isn't in 'world hello'
So, what is in 'world hello' ?

- 'world', 'hello', ' ' (space) and '' (the empty string).
- And all possible *substrings*  (characters and consecutive characters in the source
  string, so for example 'h', 'he', 'hel', ' wo', etc.). And note that all items in fact 'world', 'hello', ' ' and '' are substrings to :-)

So, all of this evaluates to true:

```
# string2 = 'world hello'
'world' in string2
'hello' in string2
' ' in string2
'' in string2
'h' in string2
'e' in string2
'llo' in string2
'llo 'wo' in string2
# etc.
```

In computer science, a string is a sequence of characters.
Each sub-sequence is a substring.

So now, you should have a better understanding of what is a string and what is a substring and you could/should search some informations on the internet if you're interested.

So, what does the `in` expression ?
The `in` expression, in fact, when working with strings, tells you if the character of the string you're searching in another string, is a *substring* of this *string* or not.

To conclude, the sequence of characters 'hello world' is not in the sequence of characters 'world hello'.

Comment: This is a very thorough explanation - Thank you for breaking it down like that!

I wanted to better understand this part of your answer:
"
Part 1 (string1 in string2) :
It evaluates to False, because 'hello world' isn't in 'world hello'
"

- Forgive me for sounding stupid here but the strings 'hello world' and 'world hello' look the same to me, except they are the other way around, right? I would have thought that the 'in' operator detected this reversal? Apologies again for my lack of understanding!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll add an example at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer and adding examples! I have modified my code to include a "for" loop and and "if" statement, which appears to work even if the words are switched around... I will most probably have to experiment more with this - Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your If statement is checking 2 condition:

1. string1 in string2 : which is False because string1 is 'hello world' and it is not present in string2. if string1 would be 'hello' or 'world' or 'world hello' or ' ' it will return True because all these are present in string2.
2. string2 not in string1 :It will check whether string2 is not present in string1 your function is returning True because of this condition, 'world hello' is not present in string1

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @NoobCoder , your program is returning true because of the second condition:

> "or string2 not in string1" which is returning TRUE, as the second string IS NOT in first string.

Then, as you have your conditions: Cond1 OR Cond2, if any of them return TRUE, your final answer will be TRUE.

Answer (score -1):

hey :D I think that you can use a for loop to check if string1 contains words in string2  Idk how to put a python code here since I'm a newbie too :\

---

but the whole thing is like

---

for a (a variable) in b (a string, list, etc):

---

```
for c in d:
```

---

then code the rest

Comment: `for a in d` iterates over the iteratable d. I think it does not really help checking wether a is contained in d. Instead it just runs the loop-body for each element of d.